# How to use api inside React Js component in web?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new in React.js web development, I am stuck to use API inside component. I've shared code:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items = []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const requestOptions = {
            method = "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
        };
        fetch("https://website/api/home",requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
        
          });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Help you with what, exactly?  What isn't working in your code?  Also, why are you using a `constructor` and `componentDidMount` in a functional component with hooks?  I wouldn't expect anything to execute those functions you're defining.  This seems like an odd mix of different structures of React.

Comment: how can I call api inside function?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing class-based React components with function-based React components.  In the latter you don't define functions like `constructor` and `componentDidMount`.  Instead, you use the React hooks to perform similar operations.  In your component you'd start by defining your initial state:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Then you can use the `useEffect` hook to invoke an operation once when the component first mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {

}, []);
```

By passing it an empty dependency array at the end you are essentially telling it to perform the operation only once for this component.  If you were to include values in that array then it would repeat the operation any time one of those values changes.

Within this operation is where you'd invoke the API call and update state with the result:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
  };
  fetch("https://website/api/home",requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // HERE you would call setShow and/or setItems to update your state
    });
}, []);
```

After all of that is where your functional component would return the actual JSX which renders the component, and within that JSX is where you'd make use of your state values.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: In the above code I also quietly corrected a typo you had.  Your `requestOptions` object was using invalid syntax to build the object.  One of your three properties had an `=` to assign the value instead of an `:` like the other two.

Comment: Now getting blocked by CORS Policy issue.

Comment: @ManishTiwari: That's a separate issue entirely, unrelated to the original question.  A quick search on your favorite search engine will find lots of information about CORS, as well as existing Stack Overflow questions which have addressed it.  You are encouraged to take a look at those and see if you can resolve the issue.  It's entirely possible that the API simply doesn't allow cross-origin requests and won't allow you to use it in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo by the way here

```
method = "POST",
```

you can't do this in object.

It should be

```
method: "POST",
```

What about API: just assign your response to local state. Something like this

```
.then(data => {
  this.setState(state => {
    return {
     ...state,
     state.items: data
    }
  })
});
```